# Addition of Polynomials c++

Tags: c++

I have written a class for polynomials. everything is working, except the addition of polynomials. It's running, but i get this output:

```
an empty polynomial has been created!
an empty polynomial has been created!
an empty polynomial has been created!
please input a polynomial.
```

What is going wrong there? I suppose that the function add isn't correct, but i cant see the bug.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class poly
{
public:

    poly();//constructor

    ~poly();//destructor

    void add(poly ,poly); //addition
    void output();
    void input();

private:
    map<int,float> polymap; 
};

poly::poly()//constructor
{
    cout<<"an empty polynomial has been created!"<<endl;
}

void poly::input()
{
    cout << "please input a polynomial."  <<endl;

    int key;
    while (cin >> key && key != -1)
        cin >> polymap[key];

    cout<<"the polynomial "<<endl;
    output();
    cout<<" has been created."<<endl;
}

poly::~poly()
{
    cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;
    polymap.clear() ;//deletes the polynomial
    cout <<"the polynomial" <<endl;
    output();
    cout << "will be deleted now."<<endl;
    polymap.clear();
}

void poly::add(poly v,poly w)
{
    map<int,float>::iterator iterv=(v.polymap).begin();
    map<int,float>::iterator iterw=(w.polymap).begin();

    polymap.clear();

    while(++iterv!=(v.polymap).end())
        polymap[iterv->first]+=iterv->second;
    while(++iterw!=(w.polymap).end())
        polymap[iterw->first]+=iterw->second;
}

void poly::output()//uebergabe des iterators
{
    map<int,float>::iterator iter=polymap.begin();

    cout<<"("<<iter->second <<")*X^"<< iter->first;
    while (++iter!=polymap.end())
        cout <<"+("<< iter->second <<")*X^"<< iter->first;
    cout <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    poly f;
    poly g;
    poly c;

    g.input();
    f.input();

    c.add(f,g);
    cout<<"f+g = "<<endl;
    c.output();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: `add` should have the signature `void poly::add(poly const& v,poly const& w)`

Comment: There is no need to call `polymap.clear()` in your destructor.  Since the map is a member of your `poly` class, it will be cleaned up automatically when the `poly` object is destroyed.

Comment: The calls of `g.input()` and `f.input()` require you to enter data, otherwise the `add()` function will never be called.   What input are you providing?

Answer (score 0):

The first three lines of `main` are

```
poly f;
poly g;
poly c;
```

This creates three polynomials, calling each one’s default constructor. You put an output statement in there, so it’s printing output for each one.

The next line, `g.input();`, calls `poly::input` on `g`; the first line of this is another output statement.

If you don’t enter anything, you never get beyond that and never call `poly::add`, so that function isn’t even being called. Whether or not it’s correct, you won’t see anything until you enter two polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is in the iteration over the maps.
Your `add` should instead be:

```
void poly::add(poly v,poly w)
{
    map<int,float>::iterator iterv=(v.polymap).begin();
    map<int,float>::iterator iterw=(w.polymap).begin();

    polymap.clear();

    while(iterv!=(v.polymap).end()){ //not incremented here
        polymap[iterv->first]+=iterv->second;
        iterv++; //increment is now here
    }

    while(iterw!=(w.polymap).end()){ //not incremented here
        polymap[iterw->first]+=iterw->second;
        iterw++; //increment is now here
    }

}
```

In your code as soon as you entered the loop to `add` you had already advanced to the second element.

For the show you write the first element differenty, but you must test if it exists:

```
void poly::output()//uebergabe des iterators
{
    map<int,float>::iterator iter=polymap.begin();


    if (iter == polymap.end()) return; //can't show first element if it doesn't exist

    cout<<"("<<iter->second <<")*X^"<< iter->first;

    while (++iter!=polymap.end())
        cout <<"+("<< iter->second <<")*X^"<< iter->first;
    cout <<endl;

}
```

The `output` was actually looping infinitely when called from your destructor, because you didn't have any element.

Also you should pass both polys to the `add` method by reference as suggested in the comments, as well as remove the `clear` calls in the destructor.

Comment: Thank You Isac helped me out a lot!